# convert query from mysql client to sequelize syntax

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

i working sequelize with nodejs , i try convert my query codes from mysql query to sequelize syntax can you help me on this ?

mysql query :

```
select username,message,fromUserId,toUserID from messages inner join messageToUsers on messages.id = messageToUsers.messageID left outer join users on messages.fromUserID = users.id where messageToUsers.`toUserID` = 5 and messages.`fromUserId` = 7 or messageToUsers.`toUserID` = 7 and messages.`fromUserId` = 5
```

sequlize query

```
    Message.hasMany(MessageToUser,{foreignKey:'messageID'});
    Message.belongsTo(Users,{foreignKey:'fromUserId'});
    Message.findAll({where:{fromUserId :5,fromUserID : 7},
        include :[
            {model:MessageToUser,where:{toUserID:5,toUserID:7}} ,
            {model:Users,attributes:['id','username']}
        ]

    }).then(function(messages) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(messages));
        res.status(200).json(messages);


    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your attributes

```
Message.hasMany(MessageToUser,{foreignKey:'messageID'});
Message.belongsTo(Users,{foreignKey:'fromUserId'});
Message.findAll({where:{fromUserId :5,fromUserID : 7},
    include :[
        {model:MessageToUser,where:{toUserID:5,toUserID:7}} ,
        {model:Users,attributes:['id','username']}
    ],
    attributes: ["username","message", "toUserId", "fromUserId"]  //<-HERE

}).then(function(messages) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(messages));
    res.status(200).json(messages);


});  //<- you also missed a semicolon here.
```

Second thing I noticed. If you use the same field two times in the same Model in your `where`, one of them will be ignored. You need to use `$and`.

```
{model:MessageToUser,where:{
    $and: {[toUserID:5],
           [toUserID:7]}
}}
```

Note: missing semicolons at the end of a statement usually won't cause your application to fail but is best practice to be consistent, either always use them or always omit them.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem thanks everybody

```
    Message.hasMany(MessageToUser,{foreignKey:'messageID',as: 'model1'});
    Message.belongsTo(Users,{foreignKey:'fromUserId'});
    Message.findAll({where:{$or:[{'$model1.toUserId$':toUserId,fromUserId:fromUserID},{'$model1.toUserId$':fromUserID,fromUserId:toUserId}]},
        include :[
            {attributes: ["toUserId"],model:MessageToUser,as: 'model1'} ,
            {attributes: ["username"],model:Users}
        ]

    }).then(function(messages) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(messages));
        res.status(200).json(messages);


    });
```